# How does the :: operator syntax work in the context of bounded typeclass?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and trying to understand the reasoning behind it's syntax design at the same time. Most of the syntax is beautiful.

But since `::` normally is like a type annotation, How is it that this works:

```
Input: minBound::Int

Output: -2147483648
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the conflict you are trying to set up with this question. For example, you ask why this has the same syntax as the "has type" operator... but it *is* the "has type" operator! Similarly, you say normally `::` is like a type annotation; and then you show an example where `::` is used as a type annotation (and imply that this is not the normal use... but it is the normal use).

Comment: Does it help to know that `::` is syntax, not an operator? "Operator" in Haskell has a specific meaning - an infix function that can be sectioned. There are several tokens made from operator characters that are reserved as syntax instead, like `<-`, `->`, `|`, and `::`. (That list is not exhaustive.) They aren't operators, and they don't work like operators. They're just syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no separate operator: `::` is a type annotation in that example.  Perhaps the best way to understand this is to consider this code:

```
main = print (f minBound)

f :: Int -> Int
f = id
```

This also prints `-2147483648`.  The use of `minBound` is inferred to be an `Int` because it is the parameter to `f`.  Once the type has been inferred, the value for that type is known.

Now, back to:

```
main = print (minBound :: Int)
```

This works in the same way, except that `minBound` is known to be an `Int` because of the type annotation, rather than for some more complex reason.  The `::` isn't some binary operation; it just directs the compiler that the expression `minBound` has the type `Int`.  Once again, since the type is known, the value can be determined from the type class.

Answer (score 3):

`::` still means "has type" in that example.

There are two ways you can use `::` to write down type information. Type declarations, and inline type annotations. Presumably you've been used to seeing type declarations, as in:

```
plusOne :: Integer -> Integer
plusOne = (+1)
```

Here the `plusOne :: Integer -> Integer` line is a *separate* declaration about the identifier `plusOne`, informing the compiler what its type should be. It is then actually defined on the following line in another declaration.

The other way you can use `::` is that you can embed type information in the middle of any expression. Any expression can be followed by `::` and then a type, and it means the same thing as the expression on its own except with the additional constraint that it must have the given type. For example:

```
foo = ('a', 2) :: (Char, Integer)
bar = ('a', 2 :: Integer)
```

Note that for `foo` I attached the entire expression, so it is very little different from having used a separate `foo :: (Char, Integer)` declaration. `bar` is more interesting, since I gave a type annotation for just the `2` but used that within a larger expression (for the whole pair). `2 :: Integer` is still an expression for the **value** `2`; `::` is not an operator that takes `2` as input and computes some result. Indeed if the `2` were already used in a context that requires it to be an `Integer` then the `:: Integer` annotation changes nothing at all. But because `2` is normally polymorphic in Haskell (it could fit into a context requiring an `Integer`, or a `Double`, or a `Complex Float`) the type annotation pins down that the type of *this* particular expression is `Integer`.

The use is that it avoids you having to restructure your code to have a separate declaration for the expression you want to attach a type to. To do that with my simple example would have required something like this:

```
two :: Integer
two = 2

baz = ('a', two)
```

Which adds a relatively large amount of extra code just to have something to attach `:: Integer` to. It also means when you're reading `bar`, you have to go read a whole separate definition to know what the second element of the pair is, instead of it being clearly stated right there.

---

So now we can answer your direct question. `::` has no special or particular meaning with the `Bounded` type class or with `minBound` in particular. However it's *useful* with `minBound` (and other type class methods) because the whole point of type classes is to have overloaded names that do different things depending on the type. So selecting the type you want is useful!

`minBound :: Int` is just an expression using the value of `minBound` under the constraint that this particular time `minBound` is used as an `Int`, and so the value is `-2147483648`. As opposed to `minBound :: Char` which is `'\NUL'`, or `minBound :: Bool` which is `False`.

None of those options mean anything different from using `minBound` where there was already some context requiring it to be an `Int`, or `Char`, or `Bool`; it's just a very quick and simple way of *adding* that context if there isn't one already.

---

It's worth being clear that both forms of `::` are **not** operators as such. There's nothing terribly wrong with informally using the word operator for it, but be aware that "operator" has a specific meaning in Haskell; it refers to symbolic function names like `+`, `*`, `&&`, etc. Operators are first-class citizens of Haskell: we can bind them to variables<sup>1</sup> and pass them around. For example I can do:

```
(|+|) = (+)

x = 1 |+| 2
```

But you cannot do this with `::`. It is "hard-wired" into the language, just as the `=` symbol used for introducing definitions is, or the `module Main ( main ) where` syntax for module headers. As such there are lots of things that are true about Haskell operators that are not true about `::`, so you need to be careful not to confuse yourself or others when you use the word "operator" informally to include `::`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually an operator is just a particular kind of variable name that is applied by writing it between two arguments instead of before them. The same function can be bound to operator and ordinary variables, even at the same time.

Comment: I wish more Haskell answers were like this, thorough and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another example, with Monads you can play a little like this:

```
import Control.Monad

anyMonad :: (Monad m) => Int -> m Int
anyMonad x = (pure x) >>= (\x -> pure (x*x)) >>= (\x -> pure (x+2))

$>  anyMonad 4 :: [Int]
=> [18]
$>   anyMonad 4 :: Either a Int
=> Right 18
$>   anyMonad 4 :: Maybe Int
=> Just 18
```

it's a generic example telling you that the functionality may change with the type, another example:

Comment: "another example:" ... ? something's missing. :)